# References for the non-Abelian gauge covariant Laplace equation?

Tags: resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, greens-functions

Is there a standard reference which discusses solutions to the non-Abelian gauge covariant Laplace equation $D_{\mu} D^{\mu} \phi = 0$, where $D_{\mu} \phi = \partial_{\mu} + ig[A_{\mu}, \phi]$? Note that $\phi$ is adjoint here (matrix-valued), although I'm sure I could adapt a discussion for a fundamental $\phi$.

I am uncertain how to adapt a standard Green's function approach (c.f. chapter 1 from Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics*) from the standard Laplace equation $\partial_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \phi = 0$ to solving the non-Abelian gauge covariant Laplace equation.